# Client(ajax)-server(jsp) json data communication

Tags: ajax, json, jsp

I am trying to send json data from client using AJAX and JavaScript. My client side code is working finely( I have tried to print the json data at client itself and succeeded in it). Server side I have to use jsp. I have included necessary jar files too in Web-INF.
Can Someone help in debugging this error
 **An exception occurred processing JSP page at line:
JSONObject json_obj = (JSONObject)parser.parse(test);**

**This is my json data:
 [{"firstname":"jayesh","lastname":"talreja"}]
Server side jsp code:**

```
<%@ page import="org.json.simple.JSONArray" %>
<%@ page import="org.json.simple.JSONObject" %>
<%@ page import="org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser" %>
<%@ page import="org.json.simple.parser.ParseException" %>
<%
    String test = (String)request.getParameter("JSON_OBJ");
    out.print(test);
    System.out.println(test);
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject json_obj = (JSONObject)parser.parse(test);
    /*String input = (String)jsonObject;
    /*Object obj = parser.parse(test);
    JSONArray array = (JSONArray)obj;*/
    String firstName = (String)json_obj.get("firstname");
    String lastName = (String)json_obj.get("lastname");
    System.out.println("FirstName:" + firstName + "LastName:" + lastName);
    //System.out.println(input);
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fist: If this `[{"firstname":"jayesh","lastname":"talreja"}]` is your JSON Data, the functioncalls `(String)json_obj.get("firstname")` and `(String)json_obj.get("lastname")` will fail, because the Object is wrapped in an Array.

Second: The given JSON data is valid. (Check it [here](http://jsonlint.com/)). Are you sure that there is no other characters before or after the JSON Data? Can you give me more Details of the Exception?

Third: Have you tried other JSON datas or other parser?

Comment: Hi! there are no more characters before or after json data.No I havn't tried any JSON datas or parser.my server side code now is :           <%@ page import="org.json.simple.JSONArray" %>
<%@ page import="org.json.simple.JSONObject" %>
<%@ page import="org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser" %>
<%@ page import="org.json.simple.parser.ParseException" %>
<%
 String test = (String)request.getParameter("JSON_OBJ");
 out.print(test);
 System.out.println(test);
 JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
 JSONObject json_obj = (JSONObject)parser.parse(test);
%>

Answer (score 0):

More details of exception!
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /test/jayesh_server.jsp at line 10

7:

```
out.print(test);
8:  System.out.println(test);
9:  JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
10:     JSONObject json_obj = (JSONObject)parser.parse(test);
11: %>  
12: 
13: 


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:575)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:477)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    java.io.StringReader.<init>(StringReader.java:50)
    org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:79)
    org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:75)
    org.apache.jsp.test.jayesh_005fserver_jsp._jspService(jayesh_005fserver_jsp.java:75)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```